# Phonegap : Loading content of apps dynamically

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am working on Phonegap android app which should take the content from my remote server.

After searching the things I found the 2 ways of getting the contents from remote server to phonegap App :

**1. Getting the content using Ajax call to remote server by returning
        the json data from remote server PHP file.**

**2. Getting complete HTML page from remote server using Ajax.**

If i am going to implement one of the above,  my app is going to send the request each and every time while loading the page which i think not a good idea.

I know very well how to implement above mentioned option in my App.
 but i wanted to know which one is efficient.

How i can accomplished this? 
  I am also using the Jquery mobile.

Comment: you look for efficiency and use jquery mobile? lol. Best choice is returning JSON, as JSON data should be smaller, that means faster download, less data consumtion.

Comment: Is there any other solution that you would like to suggest?

Comment: intel's app framework, kendo mobile, ionic, etc. jquery mobile can be good for websites, but it doesn't perform well on phonegap apps on old android phones